# Runtime of nested for loops is O(n^2)?

Tags: runtime, big-o

I have these nested loops

```
int sum = 0;
for (int n = N; n > 0; n = n/2) {
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      sum++;
   }
}
```

The outer loop throws me off a little bit.
Is the runtime still O(n^2) or it's something else?

Comment: How many times does the outer loop run? If the loop keeps following n = n/2 until n > 0, does that mean it's an infinite loop?

Answer (score 2):

Here the inner loop executes 1 + 2 + ... + n/2 + n times. 
It has lg n terms in this sequence, and that does mean that int i = 0 executes lg n times,

The sum for the statement(s) in the inner loop is 2n. 
So we get O(n + lg n) = O(n)

Comment: How many times does the outer loop run? If the loop keeps following n = n/2 until n > 0, does that mean it's an infinite loop?